# Ошибка при вызове класса Instance из библиотеки umongo

Tags: python, aiogram, mongodb, pymongo

Вызов:

```
from umongo import Instance


instance = Instance()

Product.init(instance)
Category.init(instance)
Person.init(instance)


class Product(Document):
    name = fields.StringField(required=True, validate=validate.Length(max=255))
    price = fields.FloatField(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=0))
    description = fields.StringField()
    quantity = fields.IntField(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=0))


class Category(Document):
    name = fields.StringField()



class Person(Document):
    name = fields.StringField(required=True, validate=validate.Length(max=255))
    number = fields.IntField(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=8))
```

сама ошибка:

```
    instance = Instance()
               ^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Instance with abstract method is_compatible_with
```

Как с ним работать?
пробовал @instance.register но всё равно ошибка.